# Pushing element of an array as part of an object in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I have this class:

```
export default class Player {
  constructor() {
    this.scores = [];
  }

 // Insert a new score and keep top N
 insertScore = (score) => {
    this.scores.push(score);
    this.scores.sort((a, b) => b - a);
    if (this.scores.length > N) this.scores.pop();
  };
}
```

Which is part of a component state:

```
export default class Menu extends React.PureComponent {
   contructor(props){
     super(props);
     this.state = {
       player: new Player()
     }
   }

   onEndGame(score) {
     player.insertScore(score);
   }
   ...
}
```

Since changing arrays as part of the state it's very tricky in React (as explained in [this](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-state-array-add-update-remove/) aritcle), is the `insertScore` "legal" in this context?

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying directly a nested property of the state (`this.state.player.scores`) so it's not correct.

I'll try this:

**Player class**

```
insertScore = (score) => {
    this.scores.push(score);
    this.scores.sort((a, b) => b - a);
    if (this.scores.length > N) this.scores.pop();

    return this;
};
```

**Menu class**

```
onEndGame(score) {
    this.setState({
       player: this.state.player.insertScore(score);
    });
}
```